# How can I force an absolute position on a div inside a -webkit-transform chain?

Tags: google-maps, css, d3.js, webkit-transform

A simplified form of my original question.  Given the code below (for Chrome/Safari), how can I make the "text" in the inner div appear at top left, without knowing the values in the transformation matrix of the outer div?

```
<body>
  <div style="-webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 50);">
    <div style='background-color: #f00; -webkit-transform: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: fixed'>text</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

No matter what I try in terms of CSS, I can't make the inner div ignore the outer transform().  From the spec it seems like -webkit-transform: none should clear the stack of transforms, and/or position: fixed; but nothing works for me.  I've tried related code in Firefox ('transform') with same issue.

Original formulation:  I'm trying to use [D3JS to draw into an SVG container](http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6511981) that is set up as a google.maps.OverlayView and positioned directly on top of my google map container, both 600x400 fixed position at top left.  You can see the [code in gist here](https://gist.github.com/patricksurry/6511981).

This works fine until you drag the map, at which point it is repositioning my SVG container, apparently due to the -webkit-transform: matrix(...) in one of the parent divs: if I toggle that line off in Chrome DevTools, my overlayview comes back to the right place.  I need the overlayview to stay aligned with the map viewport, since I am refreshing the content when the map moves.

Comment: It sounds like your overlay div should be completely separate so that you can position it independently.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a choice since it's put there by google maps API. If I draw as a separate div, then I don't think I can interleave it between the google tile layer and the map controls.